# Find exponent of the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_{385}$

Tags: group-theory

I know that if I want to find the exponent of the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ for example, I will simply list the units $\{1,5\}$, write down the order of each ($1$ and $2$ respectively) and see that the exponent of this group of units is $2$.

In the case of $\mathbb{Z}_{385}$, is there any way to do this a bit more easily? It seems insane to find every unit and its order.

Comment: I think what you need is the charmichael lambda function of $385$, which can be calculated by taking the lcm of the charmichael lambdas of the prime power factors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Computing_%CE%BB(n)_with_Carmichael's_theorem

Comment: @Yorch Thanks for the reply, that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reason this way.
Since

$
\mathbb{Z}_{385}\cong\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_7\times\mathbb{Z}_{11},
$

the group of units

$
\mathbb{Z}_{385}^*=\mathbb{Z}_{5}^*\times\mathbb{Z}_{7}^*\times\mathbb{Z}_{11}^*=C_4\times C_6\times C_{10}.
$

The exponent of this group is $4\cdot3\cdot5=60$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. What do C4, C6 and C10 mean and why do they correspond to values of 4, 3, and 5?

Comment: $C_4$, $C_6$ and $C_{10}$ are cyclic groups of orders 4, 6, and 10. We have to calculate the least common multiple of these numbers.